# Awk, printing certain columns based on how rows of different files match

Tags: bash, unix, awk, command-line

I am pretty sure that it is awk I would have to use
I have one file with information I need and another file where I need to take two pieces of information from and obtain two numbers from the second file based on that piece of information.
So if the first file has m7 in its fifth column and 3 in it's third column I want to search in the second column for a row that has 3 in it's first column and m7 in it's fourth column. The I want to print certain columns from these files as listed below.

Given the following two files of input
file1

```
1 dog   3   8   m7  n15 
50 cat  5   8   m15 m22
20 fish 6   3   n12 m7
```

file2

```
3   695 842 m7  word
5   847 881 m15 not
8    910 920 n15 important
8   695 842 m22 word
6   312 430 n12 not
```

I want to produce the output

```
pre3   695   842   21
pre5   847   881   50
pre6   312   430   20
pre8   910   920   1
pre8   695   842   50
```

EDIT:

I need to also produce output of the form

```
pre3   695   842   pre8   910   920   1
pre5   847   881   pre8   695   842   50
pre6   312   430   pre3   695   842   20
```

The answer below work for the question before, but I'm confused with some of the syntax of it so I'm not sure how to adjust it to make this output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ar[$5,$3]=$1+ar[$5,$3]; ar[$6,$4]=$1+ar[$6,$4]}
     NR>FNR && ar[$4,$1] {print "pre"$1,$2,$3,ar[$4,$1]}' file1 file2
```

outputs `pre` plus the content of the second file's first, second, and third column and the first file's first column for all lines in which the content of the first file's fifth and third (or sixth and fourth) column is identical to the second file's fourth and first column:

```
pre3 695 842 21
pre5 847 881 50
pre8 910 920 1
pre8 695 842 50
pre6 312 430 20
```

(for lines with more than one match the values of ar[$4,$1] are summed up)

Note that the output is not necessarily sorted! To achieve this: add `sort`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ar[$5,$3]=$1+ar[$5,$3]; ar[$6,$4]=$1+ar[$6,$4]}
     NR>FNR && ar[$4,$1]{print "pre"$1,$2,$3,ar[$4,$1]}' file1 file2 | sort
```

**What does the code?**

- `NR==FNR{...}` works on the first input file only
- `NR>FNR{...}` works on the 2nd, 3rd,... input file
- `ar[$5,$3]` creates an array whose key is the content of the 5th and 3rd column of the current line / record (separated by the field separator; usually a single blank)

Comment: Thanks, this is super close, but because pre3 695 to 842 appears twice i want the 4th column to be 21 instead of 20, do you know how to make this adjustment?

Comment: Thank-you, also, would you explaining what the code is doing a little bit, I'm pretty lost @F. Knorr

Comment: I have added some explanations. If something is not clear, please ask!

Comment: What are the NR==FNR{...} and NR>FNR{...} actually doing other than just working on those files @F. Knorr

Comment: NR is the number of the record and FNR stands for the number of the record in each file. Think of NR as the total number of lines read and of FNR as the line number of the current input file. See: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/

Comment: I'm confused with the specific's like why do you set NR==FNR and NR>FNR I'm confused what kind of effect this would have. I don't why the NR==FNR would have any effect an the output

Comment: I especially don't get the NR>FNR part but the other part is starting to make sense as as look at other forum pages

Comment: The logical expression NR>FNR is false for the first file and true for all other files. For the first file NR is identical to FNR. As soon as awk reaches the second file FNR is set to 1 again, whereas NR keeps being incremented...  
In general, a logical expression that precedes `{...}` decides whether `{...}` is executed: For instance, in `4==3{print "a"}` the value "a" will never be printed

Comment: Thank-you! Do you know how I would solve my edit I posted?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below command :

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$3 FS $5]=1;next } a[$1 FS $4]' f1.txt f2.txt
```

If you want to print only the specific fields from the matching lines in second file use like below :

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$3 FS $5]=1;next } a[$1 FS $4] { print "pre"$1" "$2" "$3}' f1.txt f2.txt
```